# Selenium: Unable to create folder and file for download in the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

The test is to download a file by clicking the link for download template. When I execute the script in my local machine, it is working perfectly. Able to create the download folder and the file downloaded is stored in the newly created "download" folder.
But when I integrate it to the jenkins pipeline, there is no folder created and no file downloaded.
Note: In the jenkins pipeline, the script is executed using chrome in the selenium grid. Please refer to the configuration in the chrome driver.

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\downloads");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(seleniumGridUrl), cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to check the contents of the downloaded file in your test, I'd like to suggest using a kind of by-pass approach. Using HTTP library, you may just execute Head http call to the resource, you need to download. In the response you'll get the file type and its size. In your test you simply assert against them to validate correctness of accessed for downloading file.
I think the issue you get is connected somehow with the permissions, that does not allow creating folders / files on the environment, where test is executed.